# react-router v3 - v5 PlainRoute migration

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I've begun working on a rather large react project in which a large upgrade to the libraries is required.
Most migrations for non-supported libraries has gone smooth, but the combination of react-redux and react-router v4-5 is could cause a bit of issue, due to the initial implementation of plain routes (in combination with a fractal design pattern)

In the meantime, I have migrated to react-router v3.2.3 as it handles the newer version of react-redux.  However, this is just moving the goal post.

Here is an example of the nested routes

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path        : '/',
  indexRoute  : { component: AuthLoginContainer },
  childRoutes : [
    DashboardRoute(store),
    SettingsRoute(store)
  ]
})


// DashboardRoute index.js
export default (store) => ({
  path : 'dashboard',
  indexRoute: { component: DashboardContainer },
  component: isAuthContainer(BaseLayout),
  childRoutes: [ ProfileRoute(store) ]
})
     // ProfileRoute index.js
      export default (store) => ({
      path : 'profile',
      indexRoute: { component: ProfileContainer },
     })
```

The example on https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config seems to work somewhat, but I'm unsure how to implement a similar pattern with the newer version of react-router

Any tips on how to even begin to tackle this (if possible) or how similar patterns are implemented in react-router5 would be appreciated.

I'm hoping it's not a full rewrite as the fractal design with these routes is pretty baked into the application

Comment: Looks like you have some heavy coupling of react-router-dom/routing and redux... react-router-dom v5 is completely separate from any redux stores. I'm unfamiliar with the fractal design pattern but I can honestly say I've *never* seen anything like this in react-router-dom 2+ years working with v5. It may be time for some rearchitecturing if you can't stay at the version you're at.

Comment: That's the conclusion that I've come to right now as well.  Is that without a major architectural change to move away from the fractal that react-router is pretty locked at v3.2.3 (which has so far seemed to work with react-redux@latest.

Might still have to look into upgrading at some point.  Might just have to build up a proposal/time frame and see what the higher-ups think